# do not move another page in angular js when click button through ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

the following code , i will try in my best , but i don't get any answer , when click on the button so the another page will not be open ...

**HTML**

```
   <button class="button button-small button-block button-positive sign-up" 
           type="button" 
           name="button" 
           ng-click="signUp()">
       Sign up
   </button>
```

**app.js**

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
  {
       $stateProvider
     .state('home',{
                url:'/home',
                abstract:true,
                templateUrl:'templates/home/home.html',
                controller:'LoginCtrl'

              })
      .state('home.login', {
      url: '/login',
      views:{
        'home':{
                  templateUrl: 'templates/home/login.html',
                  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
               }
            }
  })
  .state('home.signup',{
    url: '/signup',
    view:{
      'signup':{
                  templateUrl: 'templates/home/signup.html',
                  controller:'RegisterCtrl'
                }
        }
  })
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup,$state,$location) {
     $scope.data = {};
     $scope.login = function() {
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password)
            .success(function(data) {
                 $state.go( 'home.main' );
               })
            .error(function(data) {
                  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Login failed!',
                        template: 'Please check your username or password !'
                  });
            });
      }
   $scope.signUp = function(){
        $location.path('/home.signup');
    }
 })
```

**Service**

```
 angular.module('nt-wallet.services',[])
  .service('LoginService', function($q) {
    return {
    loginUser: function(name, pw) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        if (name == 'ntt' && pw == 'fds') {
            deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
        }else if (name=='' && pw=='') {
            deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');

        } else {
            deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
        }
        promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
})
```

in the above code, when I click on the button so the next page will not be open .. so give me the solution ... i try several like location.href, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$state.go('home.signup');` or `$location.path('/home/signup');` instead of `$location.path('/home.signup');`

*Edit:*
Using $state.go is preferable, since you're using the ui.router.

You could also use `<button ui-sref="home.signup">` instead of a controller function.

Comment: @kvetis i think $location.path('/home/signup'); would be the correct solution what you say?

Comment: @AmitSirohiya You are right. I updated my answer. (Although using $state.go()) is still preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using **$stateProvider** so dont use **$location** to redirect, you have to change state.

In your controller do something like this -

```
$scope.signUp = function(){
    $state.go('home.signup');
};
```

Comment: Have you injected $state in controller function?

Comment: Can you make a plunker?

Comment: Yeah it would be easy to find bug.